# In ruby, what usage will trigger Kernel#autoload?

Tags: ruby

[`Kernel#autoload`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload) is documented as follows:

> Registers filename to be loaded (using Kernel::require) the first time that module (which may be a String or a symbol) is accessed.

**What is the definition of "access"?**

I was surprised to find that an "empty" class definition triggers autoload.

```rb
# a.rb
class A
  def foo() end
end

# irb -I .
autoload :A, 'a.rb'
#=> nil
class A; end # supposedly "empty" class ..
#=> nil
A.instance_methods.include?(:foo) # .. is not "empty"!
#=> true
```

Because I used the `class` keyword, I expected the above to define an "empty" class `A`.  Specifically, I did not expect instances of `A` to respond to `foo`.  I did not expect to autoload `a.rb`.

So, what is the precise definition of "access" that triggers `autoload`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Kernel#autoload` loads when the class constant is first referenced in any way. It does not check to see whether the class is already defined, or whether it's in mid-definition.

Source: [Practicing Ruby's "Ways to Load Code"](https://practicingruby.com/articles/ways-to-load-code), `Kernel#autoload` section.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby, there is no distinction between the class definition code or any other executable code, in general.

What this means is, the following gets invoked as soon as the statement is encountered:

```
5.times { puts "Hello" }
```

In same way, the `class`'s code is executed as soon as it is defined:

```
class C
  puts "Hello"
end
=> "Hello"
```

One may wonder that the instance methods, class methods *inside* the called are not executed. The reason for that is that the methods holds *bindings* and is thus invoked on the class's instance (object) (plus, this is entirely another story).

This defines the *access* in your question. `class A` is *accessed* as soon as you defined it. As Arup told in his answer, `autoload` does *lazy loading*, and the `class/module` only gets loaded when they are *accessed*. Classes being **open** in Ruby, triggers the autoload for `class A` in `a.rb`.

Hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot make out the meaning from the `kernel` doc, `autoload` works in a similar way to `require`, but it only loads the file specified when a constant is accessed for the first time. So when you tried to extend the same class, you are accessing it for the first time and so it load the definition from file.

Take a good read at (I bookmarked it a long time back): http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html

I modified your code a bit like:

```
# a.rb
puts "I was loaded"

class A
  def foo()
  end
end
```

It will display first line and tells you when this file is loaded.

HTH